# What does the CPU usage and memory allocation indicate in the screenshot?

Tags: java, cpu-usage, heap-memory, jvisualvm

[image]

Hi

While doing memory profiling of tomcat using jvisualvm, after some time i noticed that CPU usage was almost 0 and use heap size was also constant and was not taking up more memory even after it has more available memory.(See the screen shot below).

There are no errors on tomcat or on web browser from which task was initiated. How should I interpret this, does this mean my process is dead and is not doing anything or what?

Comment: Looks like it's not doing anything (heap usage means it's not dead). It's on standby or waiting for input probably.

Comment: There is no input to be supplied, is there some way i can check what it is waiting for or where it is stuck?

Comment: Well, if it's java you could always use a debugger or println everywhere to see if you ever exit or stop somewhere. This is a server application, so why do you think it exits? Isn't it open and waiting for incoming connections?

Comment: With no activity it doesn't look like it's doing anything.